# jQuery - Append() is not working to add a button on Clicking an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkmuhfqt/1/

As you can see on jsfiddle, I made a `Readmore` text that can be clicked and it's for some functions.

Using jQuery, I tried to add a button through clicking the `Readmore` text that uses the `append()` function.

But it did not work.

Why does my `Readmore` text click not work at all in `append()`- to add some button?

I want to add `hello` button through clicking `readmore` text.

Where is my problem? How can I fix it?

-Edit-

**html :**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"  style="border:0.5px; border-style: solid;">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left media-top" style="">
                  <img src="https://6dbaudio.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/imgp0746.jpg" class="media-object pull-left img-circle" style="width:70px; height:70px;">
                </div>
                <div class="media-body" style="">
                  <p><h4 class="media-heading">hello</h4></p>
                  <p class="readmore_as_p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consesit amet, consesit amet, consesit amet, consesit amet, consesit amet, consesit amet, consesit amet, consesit amet, consectetur.
                  </p>
                 </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(".readmore_as_p").each(function () {

    var original_str = $(this).text();
    console.log("hi");
    if (original_str.length>20) {
        var subtracted_str = original_str.substr(0, 20);
        var p_plus_readmore_str = '<p class="readmore_before" data="' + original_str + '">' + subtracted_str + '...</p>';
        var link_read_more = '<a class="read_more"><p>Read more</p></a>';
        $(this).parent().children('p.readmore_as_p').html(p_plus_readmore_str+link_read_more);

        $('.read_more').click(function () {
            var originaltext = $(this).parent().children('p.readmore_before').attr('data');
            $(this).parent().html(originaltext);

            //Here is problem starting. What i ask is here.
            var text = '<div class="media" style="">\n' +
    '                    <div class="media-body text-center" style="">\n' +
    '                        <button class="btn btn-warning" style="">hello</button>' +
    '                    </div>\n' +
    '                </div>\n';
            $(this).parent().parent().append(text);
                             //To here
        });
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  (not on jsfiddle)

Comment: Please update your question to put the [mcve] **in** the question, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha).

Comment: This question is very hard to read and understand. If you are going to add a fiddle you may as well add the code to the question

Comment: Why not create a Snippet? Why post just code blocks? You took the time to make it runnable on jsFiddle (at least, I assume it was runnable).

Comment: TBH it's good that you made a working example, just there's more of a backlash recently against using jsfiddle (since the snippets were made available?)

Comment: Sorry. I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that

```
$(this).parent().html(originaltext);
```

removes the element that "this" refers to  so `$(this).parent().parent()` doesn't have a context to get parent from.

You can fix this by moving that line to under the add button line, ie:

```
$(this).parent().parent().append(text);
$(this).parent().html(originaltext);
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gkmuhfqt/2/

---

As an extra: `$('.read_more').click(function () {` should be `$('.read_more', this)...` *or* move that outside the `$(".readmore_as_p").each`

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().parent().append(text);
```

Parent element is not defined, because original $(this) (which is after debugging - a Read more link) is overwritten by your text, so there is no parent for not existing element in DOM.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkmuhfqt/3/)

It is better to create an anchor for original container:

```
var _t = $(this);
```

and use it later for appending of elements:

```
_t.append(text)
```

Nesting of parent().parent() is not very good practice.